# How to animate CSS ::backdrop behind HTML <dialog>?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dialog, backdrop

The `<dialog>` element is now cross-browser compatible (since [March 2022](https://caniuse.com/dialog)).

I tried my hand at it today and familiarised myself with:

- **HTML**

  - `<dialog>`
- **JavaScript**

  - `.show()`
  - `.showModal()`
  - `.close()`
- **CSS**

  - `::backdrop`

Everything seems straightforward but the one thing I've been unable to achieve so far is: **fading up the backdrop**.

For instance, if I want the final color of the backdrop to be:

- `background-color: rgba(0, 0, 63, 0.8);`

but have it `transition` (or `animate`) to that `background-color` from:

- `background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);`

is this even possible?

---

**Here is my (non-working) example:**

```js
const myButton = document.querySelector('button');
const myDialog = document.querySelector('dialog');

const requestDialog = () => {
  myDialog.showModal();
  setTimeout(() => myDialog.classList.add('fadeUp'), 400);
}

myButton.addEventListener('click', requestDialog, false);
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 180px;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  left: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

dialog::backdrop {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  transition: backgroundColor 0.6s ease-out;
}

dialog.fadeUp::backdrop {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 63, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Click me to<br />Request Dialog</button>

<dialog>
  <h2>My Dialog</h2>
</dialog>
```

Comment: If you use a box-shadow, it might work and be close enough to what you try to do : `dialog {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vw rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  transition:  2s ease-out;
}

dialog.fadeUp {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vw  rgba(0, 0, 63, 0.8);
  transition:  2s ease-out;
}`

Comment: Caniuse says that dialog has good browser support, but support for the actual `::backdrop` pseudo element varies WIDELY and likely transitions/animations aren't implemented yet

Comment: Thanks @ZachJensz - that's reassuring to read, since I'd rather work on the basis that `::backdrop` pseudo-element transitions and animations aren't working in April 2022 because _"We haven't got on to that yet"_ than _"That's never going to be a thing."_

Comment: [This codepen](https://codepen.io/kevinpowell/pen/PoEmLww) might help

Comment: I can't seem to get the codepen to work here, the fade in animation is fading in instantly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use a `box-shadow`, it might work and be close enough to what you try to do :

```
dialog {
   box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vw rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
   transition:  2s ease-out;
 }  
dialog.fadeUp {
   box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vw  rgba(0, 0, 63, 0.8);
   transition:  2s ease-out;
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same problem but this solved to me.

```js
const dialog = document.querySelector('.modal')

function openModal() {
  dialog.showModal(); // default dialog method
}

function closeModal() {
  dialog.classList.add('close'); // run animation here
  
  dialog.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
    dialog.classList.remove('close')
    dialog.close(); // then run the default close method
  }, {once : true}); // add this to prevent bugs when reopening the modal
}
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
}
/* when the dialog is open by its default method it adds a open tag on the element */
.modal[open] {
  display: flex;
}

.modal[open]::backdrop {
  animation: backdrop-fade 2s  ease forwards;
}

.modal.close::backdrop {
  animation: backdrop-fade 3s ease backwards;
  animation-direction: reverse;
}

@keyframes backdrop-fade {
  from {
    background: transparent;
  }
  to{
    background: rgba(0,0,0);
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="openModal()">open modal</button>
<dialog class="modal">
    <button onclick="closeModal()">close modal</button>
</dialog>
```

Comment: Nice! However the modal closes immediately if you press the Escape key, bypassing the close animation. Do you know of a workaround?

Comment: @AamirKhan The `cancel` event is not cancellable, but you can stop the Escape key from triggering it in the first place by attaching a `keydown` event to the `<dialog>` element, and `preventDefault()`ing if `e.key === 'Escape'`. Then it’s up to you to trigger the same routine to animate and then set the closed state.

Comment: My understanding is that this will not work in Firefox.

Comment: Confirmed backdrop animation does not work in Firefox. Close button also fails in Firefox.

Answer (score 3):

G-Cyrillus's answer is almost perfect! Just added the use of `max` to the box-shadow so that the shadow will cover on mobile devices.

```css
box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vmax rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71764440/19130936

Comment: This is a great suggestion, @YoshiJL. I went back to my code with the intention of updating it and then I saw that instead of `0 0 0 100vw rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);` ... I'd already written: `0 0 0 100vmax rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);`. (Great minds think alike!)

Comment: Oh that's even better! It's even better supported on older versions.

Answer (score 3):

So I wrote this function, it works fine in my chrome

```js
function getDialog(selector) {
    const dialog = selector ? document.querySelector(selector) : document.createElement('dialog')
    const oldShow = dialog.showModal
    dialog.showModal = () => {
        oldShow.call(dialog)
        dialog.classList.add('show')
    }
    const oldClose = dialog.close
    dialog.close = () => {
        dialog.addEventListener('transitionend', () => oldClose.call(dialog), {once: true})
        dialog.classList.remove('show')
    }
    return dialog
}

const dialog = getDialog('dialog')

const showBtn = document.getElementById('show-btn')
showBtn.addEventListener('click', () => dialog.showModal())

const closeBtn = document.getElementById('close-btn')
closeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => dialog.close())
```

```css
dialog {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}

dialog.show {
    opacity: 1;
}

dialog::backdrop {
    background-color: #00000000;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
}

dialog.show::backdrop {
    background-color: #00000088;
}
```

```html
<button id="show-btn">show</button>
<dialog>
  <p>hello :)</p>
  <button id="close-btn">close</button>
</dialog>
```

--- edit ---

Thanks @Destroy666 for the reminder, this is my first answer on stackoverflow, I still have a lot to do, The following is additional information:

Compared to @G-Cyrillus and @YoshiJL 's answer:

- I used the `::backdrop` selector instead of `box-shadow` alternative, which is more intuitive.

Compared to @Adriano 's answer:

- I use `transition` instead of `@keyframes` animation, which avoids the problem of not playing the complete animation caused by closing the dialog before the animation ends.
- Also works fine on Firefox.

In addition:

- I encapsulated a function to create animated dialog, and only need to pass in the html element selector, dont need to change the existing code.